# how to read file stored in local drive using Xtend

Tags: generator, xtext, xtend

how to read a json file using Xtend and using MydslGenrator ,use those file in eclipse editor

Comment: What you have tried so for ?

Comment: Share you code what you have tried so for then only SO can you help. Its nice you are interested in xtext and posting questions frequently.

Comment: do you want to read from "next to the mydsl file" or from "next to the MyDslGenerator" file

Comment: i didn't get u christian ,i have a plugin development project using eclipse swt and DSL languages, i have set of classes in an image i am reading from java  ..                                                                                                now i need to read that file( having set of classes) in a json file as arraylist ,and call those classes from eclipse editor how to do that ??

Comment: where is that file located?

Comment: while running my application i have created default work space in any of local drives with name as /runtime-EclipseApplication , i have project related folders in it i am storing file in it

Comment: Did you have a look at the read methods in ifilesystemaccess2

Comment: No,please suggest me  for reference

Answer (score 0):

First thing **MydslGenrator**  is used to generate the code from your DSL. If you want to generate code with using *JSON* file use below code in  **MydslGenrator** file

```
override void doGenerate(Resource resource, IFileSystemAccess2 fsa, IGeneratorContext context) {
 try
                {
                                URL url;
                    url = new URL("platform:/plugin/yourpackgename/foldername/yourJsonFile_Name.json");

                    try {

                        Gson gson = new Gson();
                        JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
                        reader.beginObject();
    // get your JsonObject from reader object. 
    // do your work here

    }`
```

Comment: Nothing special in the above code. Might u need gson jar. Rest is Java dependecy

Comment: thnx, i am new to Xtend and Xtext i am getting error if i apply above code my requirement is i need to read a list form a json file that dynamic one and use those those list as object in eclipse editor

Comment: I recommend you to read `implementing domain specific languages with xtext and xtend` 2nd edition book. It contains lots of stuff for beginners like you.

Comment: tq , i have ordered that one & i ll do that could u please help me out to work with above code now